# execl() is not executing a command without its absolute path

Tags: process, path, exec

I have C program saved under `/usr/sbin/`. This program prints "Hello World" every two seconds.
I can call/execute this program from any folder.

When I write C program with `system("a.out");` in it, it's executing from any folder, but when I use `execl()` I need to give the absolute path, `execl("/usr/sbin/a.out", "a.out");`, otherwise it's not executing. Why?

Comment: Isn't that what `execlp` is for?

Comment: @muru thank you very much, I didn't know

Comment: Did you try `man execl`?

Comment: @RalfFriedl thank you very much, I'll look into it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `system()` C library function uses `sh` to execute the given command.  In doing so, it does a search for the executable in the directories in `$PATH` unless the program is already specified with an absolute path.  The `execl()` C library function does not do such a lookup.

Would you want to use the `exec` family of functions to execute your program, then use `execlp()` which does do a `PATH` lookup.

See `man execlp` on your system.